Box shadow disappears when saving webpage as PDF using "Ctrl + P"
I am working on a webpage where I have applied a box shadow to an element with the following CSS
.pill-shap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 147px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.3);
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}

The box shadow is displayed correctly on the screen in the browser. However, when I press Ctrl + Pand try to save the webpage as a PDF, the box shadow disappears in the print preview and the final PDF.
I've tried adjusting the box-shadow properties, but nothing seems to work. How can I ensure that the box shadow is visible in the printed PDF version?
picture of boxes in chrome
picture of boxes In print view
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Edit : I have Checked in chrome and Firfox not working in both

Did you try the answers in this similar question?

yes i tried it but not working

Each browser's print engine has different ways to try to match HTML CSS text as PDF vectors. However Chromium programmers have spent I guess hundreds of hours, trying out different methods. For the no doubt as many different permutations of inputs.
I will leave it to others to suggest their favourite mix of styling. But simply state Chromium's can, given the correct mixed signals, produce something that is not always well suited to PDF object-ology. Here it works.

So why should we not use a line of text to enforce a shadow? Well the reason many sites switch it off when printing is the horrendous drain on resources.
That simple 20 bytes of font-less text consumes nearly 3MB of memory whilst writing.

I have intentionally altered the outer boundary so you can estimate why that can be a problem for PDF production.
The background shadow has to be defined as multiple images overlaid at different opacities to emulate a shadow. Clearly compression will help once the shadow has been constructed. However the more there are on a page, the more memory is required both when writing and reading.
Not your problem, you may think, but the use of shadows in text is to be avoided at all costs, as it severely impacts the blind, who don't see shadows but hear multiple copies of text descriptions.
HHHEEELLLLLLOOOWWW   WWWOOORRRLLLDDD
If you must have a box shape with text overlay simply use one repeatable image of a box as a background to that division. If you keep the same JPEG image at 100% it will be highly efficiently stored once used many.
This is 28.4 KB (29,155 bytes) not much larger than one of the 4 images and then overlay with translucent colour areas.

1 img = 25,947 bytes



Thanks for your answer! Using a shadow image works for me instead of using box-shadow.
